# Part number for Rheem water heater anode

Tags: water-heater, replacement, anode

Rheem 50 gallon electric heater, XE50M09EL55U1. How do I find the replacement anode rod part number for this heater?

Couldn't find it in the paper docs I have, or through a google search on the part number, or in the online pdf documents for the product.

Comment: Did you try calling the customer service number listed in the paper docs?

Comment: Do you have clearance above the tank to remove and insert a new solid anode rod? Some replacement rods are segmented to allow insertion when the overhead clearance is limited. An old anode rod can be frozen by corrosion or deposition of minerals at the threads.

Comment: I do have clearance above. I also don't know the size of the opening. I was hoping to get the new part to avoid removing and having to reinstall the current rod but that may be the quickest way.

Comment: @JACK I think it was on a weekend when I posted, let me give them a call to see if they can help.

Comment: and of course they are closed today for holiday... haha

Answer (score 1):

They are for most brands universal, ideally you want the length to match the length of the tank. The thicker and longer the anode the longer they will last. Rheem has several on their website as does Amazon.